# How to Remove html tags from string?

Tags: javascript, community, lightning

I am trying to display Text by using `RichText Field` but i am getting HTML Tags along with the text.Here is my Code.

```
 function GetDescription()
{
    try
    {
        var assetId = '{!JSENCODE(objAsset.Id)}';
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.RemoterAssetDetailView.GetDescription}',
            assetId ,
            function(result, event) {
                if(event.status)
                {
                    var jobjAsset = JSON.parse(result);
                    var strDescription = '';
                    for(var i=0;i<jobjAsset.length;i++)
                    {
                       strDescription +=html_encode(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"]);
                    }
                    j$("#divSpecification").html(strDescription);
                }
            },
            {
                escape: false
            }
        );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        //alert(e);
    }
}
```

> This is the input i am Giving :Hi who's dis Record Belongs to and New Manager For IT/Maxval Mr.&Mrs. and

getting output like this:

[image]

Can any one guide me how to slove this..!

Thanks.

Comment: What happens to that replace with a string like "did you know 3<pi and pi>4"? Doesn't that com out "did you know 34"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Tried like this. it's working

```
 function GetDescription()
{
    try
    {
        var assetId = '{!JSENCODE(objAsset.Id)}';
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.RemoterAssetDetailView.GetDescription}',
            assetId ,
            function(result, event) {
                if(event.status)
                {
                    var jobjAsset = JSON.parse(result);
                    var strDescription = '';
                    for(var i=0;i<jobjAsset.length;i++)
                    {
                       strDescription +=(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"]);
                    }
                    strDescription = strDescription.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
                    j$("#divSpecification").html(strDescription );
                }
            },
            {
                escape: false
            }
        );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        //alert(e);
    }
}
```

I have removed `strDescription +=html_encode(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"]);` html_encode

and i have filtered like this `strDescription = strDescription.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");`

Answer (score 3):

You're using the following line to encode your HTML:

```
strDescription +=html_encode(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"]);
```

You could remove the *html_encode* function, which should parse your content as HTML. Do be aware that this would introduce a security risk, as any HTML that can be added to a Rich Text field will be shown on the page.

Have a look at the following pages for more information:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/units/secdev_inject_preventing_xss_inforce